# GCC installation prefix under Linux

Tags: install, directory, gcc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where should I put software I compile myself?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30/where-should-i-put-software-i-compile-myself)

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007857/gcc-installation-prefix-under-linux) qustion, is there a recommended prefix for GCC installation under Linux? I am not trying to achieve anything too special, I just want to have the latest version of GCC while keeping everything relatively safe and working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where should I put software I compile myself?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30/where-should-i-put-software-i-compile-myself). I recommend [using stow](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30/where-should-i-put-software-i-compile-myself/85#85).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your distro but If you have stable one you don't need change GCC path default place perfect good for source installation or whatever you need for gcc and You already have latest version GCC except beta or alpha