# Have to type out whole path in order to execute an application in OSX

Tags: shell, osx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to run my own program without specifying its path](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18304/how-to-run-my-own-program-without-specifying-its-path)

One of the applications that I want to use came in a tar.gz, and I unzipped it into my home directory. Well, in order to access the application, I would have to write out the whole path of the executable file with a period at the beginning.

So, if I downloaded an application called alligator and it was in my Downloads folder, I would have to execute it by calling `./home/Downloads/alligator-folder/alligator`. Is there a way to make a shortcut so I could call the executable by just saying `alligator`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a look at the `PATH` env. variable - it seems that your question is (almost?) a duplicate of [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18304/how-to-run-my-own-program-without-specifying-its-path/).