# Install newer version of application in $HOME without root access and linking to installed app

Tags: linux, software-installation, make, source

I have this linux box without root access with a quite old emacs, so I downloaded the latest version and built as follows:

- download to `$HOME/SRC`
- configure and build in `$HOME/BLD` with `--prefix=$HOME`
- `make` and `make install`

So this creates a `bin` folder in my home directory which is what I expected.

Now when I type emacs directly from terminal, it still opens the old one (as expected). So, I have to do `~/bin/emacs`. I added this `alias emacs=$HOME/bin/emacs` to my `.bash_profile` which works. But I could have also added `~/bin` to `$PATH`. However, not quite sure which one is recommended. And would the 2 versions of emacs work without any conflict e.g. both sharing and overwriting `~/.emacs` each time a different version is opened.

Which is the best way to install new applications without root access where an older version is already present, and if the steps I followed are right.

Comment: emacs is quite large. You should discuss either upgrading the existing emacs that's installed, or supporting multiple versions of emacs with your sysadmin.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run my own program without specifying its path](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18304/how-to-run-my-own-program-without-specifying-its-path)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adjust your `PATH`. It simplifies execution, works as expected, and once you install more applications with your `$HOME` as prefix, they'll all work as expected. I'd do something like this in my RC file:

```
PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
LD_RUN_PATH=$HOME/lib:$LD_RUN_PATH
export PATH LD_RUN_PATH
```

Setting `LD_RUN_PATH` should allow locally-install DSOs to work too.

What you've done to install emacs so far is pretty much the way it's done in multi-user environments.

Clarification: paths in Unix (and other software that use them, from DOS to TeX) work like lists of places, searched left to right. On Unix, we use colons (`:`) to separate the entries. If you have a `PATH` like `/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin`, and you're looking for a program called `foo`, these paths will be searched for, in order:

1. `/usr/local/bin/foo`
2. `/bin/foo`
3. `/usr/bin/foo`

The first of these found is used. So, depending on where exactly you insert a directory, you can make your installed binaries ‘override’ others. Conceptually, the order of `PATH` is traditionally specific-to-generic or local-to-global. (of course, we often add weird paths to support self-contained third-party applications and this can break this analogy)

Comment: just to confirm, if I add `$HOME/bin` to my PATH, all programs installed there will take precedence over those (existing older versions) installed as root in `/usr/bin` and other locations in PATH? Basically does it matter to append or prepend `$HOME/bin` to PATH? e.g. `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin` instead of the above. And one more question, what if I want to install a newer version of the same program in `$HOME/bin`? I am guessing it would append the version number to the new files?

Comment: @vis: the directories in `$PATH` are tested from left to right, so `PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH` makes versions in `$HOME/bin` override the others, with `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin`, your version will only be used if no other is present.

Re the new versions: usually, no version number is appended automatically. It's probably a good idea to rename the executables/directories and put symlinks in (so `~/bin/emacs` is a symlink to `~/bin/emacs-26.3.1` which is the executable that `make install` called `emacs`).

Comment: Some info for completeness: /usr/bin is for binaries included with the distro / package manager. Place your own binaries in /opt or /usr/local/bin. That way a system upgrade won't risk wiping your manual binaries.