# where to store files from source

Tags: filesystems, compiling, source, binary

New to Linux (kinda) I'm wanting to set up my system for building from source.  I have read that packages built from source should go into /usr/local/src.  However, I have also seen on other forums some people prefer to store such packages in their home folder, saying they prefer them to be completely isolated.  I was hoping for some more input on this issue.  Where to store binaries, source packages, libararies etc.. Thank you.

Comment: Suggestion: don't do that, unless you lack admin rights. Software management is much easier if you make a package in the way that your distribution normally does and install that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where should I put software I compile myself?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30/where-should-i-put-software-i-compile-myself)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using your distribution's package manager if possible, simply because once you start installing a lot of stuff from source keeping up updates, dependencies, etc. becomes kind of a pain...  and yes, I did a LFS system...

That said, when I ran Slackware I always installed "everything" from the discs and then anything extra I wanted I would configure to be put in /opt/softwarename-version  (ie, `./configure --prefix=/opt/foo-1.3.2`)

It really doesn't matter where you install things, AS LONG AS you can easily add the libraries, binaries, etc locations to the relevant environment variables like `$PATH` and in `/etc/ld.so.conf`

Comment: Yes, I don't plan to install many things from source, only really if I need too. And to just tinker around a bit so I could learn. It's on a RPi and I do backups, so it's not so much a bother of something goes wrong. Thanks for the info